# Checking Value of every control with specific Data tag Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to check value of all html controls with data-mandatory='1'
I have tried this

```
$("[data-mandatroy='1']").each(function(i, obj) {
    alert(obj.value);
});
```

but not getting result
Here is the fiddle...
http://jsfiddle.net/pgrcs282/1/

Comment: `mandatroy` != `mandatory` ...

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/pgrcs282/3/

Comment: CTRL+C, CTRL+V is the saviour of any developer. Aside from the typo, to make the fiddle work you need to run the code in `No wrap - in <head>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this : http://jsfiddle.net/pgrcs282/16/

```
$(function () {
            $('button').click(function () {
                $.each($("[data-mandatory=1]"), function () {
                    alert($(this).val());
                });
            });
        });
```